# Create a looping request in Tornado

Tags: asynchronous, httprequest, tornado

Hi all I have this part of code:

```
self.lock_tables("write", ['confcommands'])
self.db.execute("INSERT INTO confcommands (network_id, ntype, timestamp, command) \
                 VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", nid, mynet_type, ts, cmdjson)
self.unlock_tables();

time.sleep(5)

como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port, 
                            '/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s'])

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
#response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)
request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=como_url, connect_timeout=5.0, request_timeout=5.0)
print request.request_timeout
response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
print response
```

I write a command to send to a sensor into the DB. Then, I make an http request to another DB to read the response of the sensor. There's a time between the reading of the command by the sensor and its response with the elaborations.

I thinked that with the asynchronous decorator and the yield gen.Task I could had the response like if the server is being in waiting. But instead I have to put a time.sleep in the code to stop the program and wait for the response.

There is, instead, a way to do like if the http request is being do in a loop... like if the request waiting for the response and then stop to proceed with the program.

Thank you sorry if it's confused. But it's difficult for me to explain the problem.

Comment: it seems that it IS NOT GOOD AT ALL using `time.sleep()` use `IOLoop.add_timeout` check this https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html?highlight=sleep#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout

Comment: Yes, but in any case I don't want to stop the program. I saw there's a PeriodicCallback method in Tornado? Can I use this?

Comment: am sorry, im a beginner, but the database driver is blocking, so event if you fetch the page asynchronously, everytime you call the database you block the program